# supervisord launches with wrong setuid

Tags: uwsgi, supervisord

I am trying to test a pilot system with `nginx` connecting to `uwsgi` served application controlled by `supervisord` running on ubuntu-server. Application is written in python with Flask in virtualenv, although I'm not sure if that is relevant. To test the system I have created a simple hello world with `flask`. I want nginx and uwsgi both to run as www-data user.
If I launch `uwsgi` "manually" from root shell I can see uwsgi processes runing as appropriate user (www-data). Although, if I let `supervisor` launch the application something strange happens - uwsgi processes are runing under my user (friendzis). Consequently, socket file gets created under wrong user and nginx cannot communicate with my applicaion.
**note:**  the linux server runs as `Hyper-V` VM, under Windows Server 2008.

Relevant configuration:

```
[uwsgi]

socket = /var/www/sockets/cowsay.sock
chmod-socket = 666
abstract-socket = false

master = true
workers = 2

uid = www-data
gid = www-data

chdir = /var/www/cowsay/cowsay
pp = /var/www/cowsay/cowsay
pyhome = /var/www/cowsay
module = cowsay
callable = app
```

supervisor

```
[program:cowsay]
command = /var/www/cowsay/bin/uwsgi -s /var/www/sockets/cowsay.sock -w cowsay:app
directory = /var/www/cowsay/cowsay
user = www-data
autostart = true
autorestart = true
stdout_logfile = /var/www/cowsay/log/supervisor.log
redirect_stderr = true
stopsignal = QUIT
```

I'm sure I'm missing some minor detail, but I'm unable to notice it. Would appreciate any suggestions.

Answer (score 4):

You should specify an `environment` option in the program section. For example:

```
user=chrism
environment=HOME="/home/chrism",USER="chrism"
```

See [Subprocess Environment](http://supervisord.org/subprocess.html#subprocess-environment) for details.

Also, a similar solution is proposed on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27308010/3642216)

Answer (score 0):

How do your run supervisord ? are you sure you did not run it from the shell (with your uid) ?

Are you sure you need supervisord ? You can easily attach uWSGI to upstart or systemd (eventually with the uWSGI Emperor)

Comment: I'm runing supervisord as a System V service (installed with `apt-and-friends`). `Supervisord` itself runs as root (output from `ps` confirms that).  
I've tried rebooting the VM, and logging in directly to a root shell only to witness the same result. I just can't figure out where that UID 1000 comes from.
I'm not sure if I REALLY need supervisor, but it seems to be a nice tool to control related non-WSGI apps